# php and apache thread safe error

Tags: php, apache

I am running php 5.5 and apache 2 on debian 7 (wheezy) i have installed php module for apache but it's not enable whithout enabling php module for apache i will see php files as plain text and  when i enabled php module whith a2enmod i can not start apache and it gives this error

> [crit] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
>   Pre-configuration failed
>   Action 'configtest' failed.

how can i fix this problem

Comment: @Halcyon No he does not!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The PHP manual does not recommend this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.apache2)

You can run a fast-CGI version of PHP though:

`apt-get install php5-fpm` should install it for you.

Answer (score 30):

Disabling `mpm_event` and enabling `mpm_prefork` worked for me.

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
```

Comment: Disable `mpm_event` by executing `sudo a2dismod mpm_event`

Comment: Same on debian 8. I had to install apache2-mpm-prefork and run: a2dismod mpm_event; a2dismod mpm_worker; a2enmod mpm_prefork

Comment: PS. I had to disable mpm_event first.

Comment: Enabling mpm_prefork and disabling mpm_event worked for me on **macOS High Sierra**.

Comment: Afterwards, a2enmod php7.0 works. And apache2ctl configtest works. Then restart the apache service.

Answer (score 11):

Test the Apache configuration:

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

Install PHP and PHP-FPM:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm
```

Enable Apache PHP7 module:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

Disable mpm_event module:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
```

Enable mpm_prefork module:

```
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
```

Finally restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This will resolve your error.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: To improve your answer add explanation what your code does. @J.Chomel is right about it.